How to measure standard deviation for a power test
I have a "so dumb I'm embarrassed" question about calculating power.
Suppose a paper tells me, in "Table 1", that the standard deviation of $y$ is 0.8. And then it reports an effect size on $y$ of 0.2, with an $N$ of 100 in each of treatment and control groups.
Now my assumption is that I can run, e.g. in R:
power.t.test(n = 100, delta = 0.2, sd = 0.8)

And discover
power = 0.4204383

But, is that the right standard deviation? Because the standard deviation of the two groups includes the difference between the two groups, i.e. the effect size itself. And something seems weird about that. When I simulate a situation like this, my instinct is to do e.g.
y <- rnorm(200, sd = 0.8)
y[1:100] <- y + 0.2
groups <- rep(c("Treatment", "Control"), each = 100)
lm(y ~ groups)

But here I've created a normal variable which has sd of 0.8 without including the effect size itself. So this isn't the same, right?
I'm confused, although I sense that this is indeed a stupid question in some way.

"Effect size" can mean many things, but let's say it means the standardised mean difference. If that is so, then the input delta = effect size is not correct, because according to ?power.t.test, the input delta is the mean difference (no standardisation).

Assuming the effect size is indeed the standardized mean difference you could provide that for delta while leaving the standard deviation to its default, standard value of 1.
